# How do I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, ubuntu-mate

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. However I really like it for its simplicity, usefulness and all that. I use Ubuntu on Virtualbox, but i'm sick of it stealing half my laptop resources, making both the VM and my original OS really slow. So I decided to dual boot, which I think is the best solution, because I don't want to get rid of my Windows 8.1. **BUT:**

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I WANT AN ANSWER FROM SOMEONE WHO ACTUALLY DID THIS (AND IT WORKED FOR HIM/HER)!!!**

Why, you may ask? Well because I have tried doing so before a long time ago BUT what happened is that somehow my **Windows BCD** got **corrupted** so I could not fix it and even Windows startup repair could not detect my OS and so I could not reinstall, and the rebuild BCD command did nothing, so I was left with a **BRICKED LAPTOP THAT WON'T BOOT** until my trusty friend fixed it for me somehow. (Which BTW included reinstalling Windows and starting from below zero, thanks to my extreme skillz in making backups)

So, please, if you have actually succeeded in doing so, please help me.

I don't know if you need this but I'll add it anyway:

OS: Win 8.1 Single Language.
Laptop: Dell Inspiron - 14z 5423.
Motherboard: DELL 05WDP7.
Ram: 8GB Dual Channel 1300MHz DDR3 SDRAM.
CPU: Intel Core i7-3537U.
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000 and AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series.
BIOS Version: A15.

And I want to dual boot with Ubuntu Mate.

Please if you need any other info tell me.
And don't close this question as a duplicate. ;)

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: I installed to Dell 3647 SFF system with Windows 8, now 10. It did not have separate video card just Intel video. But I fully backed up Windows. My Dell initially asked for Dell backup, Windows backup & I did a full backup with Macrium Reflect.  Then turned off UEFI Secure Boot, Windows fast start up (which Windows keeps turning on) and used Windows to shrink the NTFS partition. Reboot for chkdsk. Then booted Ubuntu & installed with Something Else. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: For MBR, create 2 primary partition, install window 8.1 to one partition, then install ubuntu to the other making sure the installer does not touch MBR, i.e., install grub to the same partition you install ubuntu not the main drive. You can add ubuntu to the windows boot manager so that you can boot windows and ubuntu, I use EasyBCD which install a grub2 file that the windows bootloader can chain boot. EasyBCD is free for home use and a small fee for business use.